# What's the inverse of block: load text in rebol / red

Tags: rebol, red

Let's say I have some rebol / red code. If I load the source text, I get a block, but how can get back the source text from block ? I tried form block but it doesn't give back the source text.

```
    text: {
        Red [Title: "Red Pretty Printer"]

        out: none   ; output text
        spaced: off ; add extra bracket spacing
        indent: ""  ; holds indentation tabs

        emit-line: func [] [append out newline]

        emit-space: func [pos] [
            append out either newline = last out [indent] [
                pick [#" " ""] found? any [
                    spaced
                    not any [find "[(" last out find ")]" first pos]
                ]
            ]
        ]

        emit: func [from to] [emit-space from append out copy/part from to]

        clean-script: func [
            "Returns new script text with standard spacing."
            script "Original Script text"
            /spacey "Optional spaces near brackets and parens"
            /local str new
        ] [
            spaced: found? spacey
            clear indent
            out: append clear copy script newline
            parse script blk-rule: [
                some [
                    str:
                    newline (emit-line) |
                    #";" [thru newline | to end] new: (emit str new) |
                    [#"[" | #"("] (emit str 1 append indent tab) blk-rule |
                    [#"]" | #")"] (remove indent emit str 1) break |
                    skip (set [value new] load/next str emit str new) :new
                ]
            ]
            remove out ; remove first char
        ]

        print clean-script read %clean-script.r
    }

    block: load text
```

Answer (score 6):

LOAD is a higher-level operation with complex behaviors, e.g. it can take a FILE!, a STRING!, or a BLOCK!.  Because it does a lot of different things, it's hard to speak of its exact complement as an operation.  *(For instance, there is SAVE which might appear to be the "inverse" of when you LOAD from a FILE!)*

But your example is specifically dealing with a STRING!:

> If I load the source text, I get a block, but how can get back the source text from block ?

As a general point, and very relevant matter: **you can't "get back" source text**.

In your example above, your source text contained comments, and after LOAD they will be gone.  Also, a very limited amount of whitespace information is preserved, in the form of the NEW-LINE flag that each value carries.  Yet what specific indentation style you used--or whether you used tabs or spaces--is not preserved.

On a more subtle note, small amounts of notational distinction are lost.  STRING! literals which are loaded will lose knowledge of whether you wrote them `"with quotes"` or `{with curly braces}`...neither Rebol nor Red preserve that bit.  (And even if they did, that wouldn't answer the question of what to do after mutations, or with new strings.)  There are variations of DATE! input formats, and it doesn't remember which specific one you used.  Etc.

But when it comes to talking about code round-tripping as text, the formatting is minor compared to what happens with binding.  Consider that you can build structures like:

```
>> o1: make object! [a: 1]
>> o2: make object! [a: 2]
>> o3: make object! [a: 3]

>> b: compose [(in o1 'a) (in o2 'a) (in o3 'a)]
== [a a a]

>> reduce b
[1 2 3]

>> mold b
"[a a a]"
```

You cannot simply serialize **b** to a string as `"[a a a]"` and have enough information to get equivalent source.  Red obscures the impacts of this a bit more than in Rebol--since even operations like `to block!` on STRING! and `system/lexer/transcode` appear to do binding into the user context.  But it's a problem you will face on anything but the most trivial examples.

There are some binary formats for Rebol2 and Red that attempt to address this.  For instance in "RedBin" [a WORD! saves its context](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/redbin.html#_word_a_id_word_a) *(and index into that context)*.  But then you have to think about how much of your loaded environment you want dragged into the file to preserve context.  So it's certainly opening a can of worms.

This isn't to say that the ability to MOLD things out isn't helpful.  But there's no free lunch...so Rebol and Red programs wind up having to think about serialization as much as anyone else.  If you're thinking of doing processing on any source code--for the reasons of comment preservation if nothing else--then PARSE should probably be the first thing you reach for.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation. Still there should have been better options like some refinement to preserve formatting structure and comment when using load or save.

Comment: @user310291 I suggest working through some examples of what you think it *should* do, and realize it's tough.  There are many difficult aspects of preserving formatting structure and comments when the source format is text characters, and [not able to reflect direct intention](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSnnfUj1XCQ).  You are presumably LOADing and then SAVEing the code for a reason...e.g. to do some manipulations of it.  But you can't really attach `;`-style comments or whitespace directly to the thing they are commenting on.  It would take a lot of guessing, and wind up wacky.

Comment: but parse is horribly over-complicated to extract NESTED sub blocks.